# NGUI How to know which drop zone my object is over?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, drag-and-drop, ngui

I am trying to create an game board by using Unity and NGUI and everything is working ok now. I am using the DragNDrop script on my dragable object and on my fields on the board I am using UIDragDropContainer. But, is there a way I can tell my dragable object which field the object is over or attaching it self to?

I have scouted the net, but have not found an solution.

Any help is appreciated :-)

Comment: Whatever object(s) is under your mouse cursor is most likely what you're dropping onto.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [UICamera.hoveredObject](http://www.tasharen.com/ngui/docs/class_u_i_camera.html#a160bd9246c107025608f9f19147a64e7) to get the last gameObject (with a collider) that the mouse or touch was last over.

Answer (score 0):

In one of my projects I came across a same issue. What I did was inherit the NGUI's `UIDragDropItem` script and created a delegate to tell me about the object. I have also added the source:

```
public class Custom_DragDropItem : UIDragDropItem {

    public delegate void DragDropDelegate(GameObject TargetObject);

    public DragDropDelegate onDragDrop;
}
```

All you have to do is use this script instead of `UIDragDropItem` on your draggable items in the inspector and register to the delegate `onDragDrop` and it will pass you the target object on which the item is dropped.